# extracting a variable from json output then debug and register the outout with ansible

Tags: json, ansible

Hi I have a problem of getting one of the variables extracted from a json output after doing a curl to be parsed and registered back to ansible

Playbook:

```
- name: debug stdout
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"
  register: dataresult

- name: debug fact
  debug:
    msg: "{{ dataresult.data.start_time_string }}"
```

output :

```
TASK [backup_api : debug stdout] 
***********************************************
task path: /home/ansible/cm-dha/roles/backup_api/tasks/main.yml:36
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
   "msg": {
       "data": [
           {
            "backup_id": 40362,
            "certified": null,
            "instance_id": 148,
            "start_time": 1506985211,
            "start_time_string": "10/03/2017 03:00:11 am"
           }
       ],
      "timestamp": 1507022232
   }
```

}

error:

fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'data'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/cm-dha/roles/backup_api/tasks/main.yml': line 48, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: debug fact\n    ^ here\n"

The error is happening when trying to extract the value start_time_string

so how to do it probably as I tried too many things like using with_items, with_dict , simulating the data[] output to debug and even doing a json query but without success

so any help here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `debug` to assign facts, use `set_fact` instead:

```
- name: debug stdout
  set_fact: 
    dataresult: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"

- name: debug fact
  debug:
    msg: "{{ dataresult.data[0].start_time_string }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to accepted answer, I've made it as below for my case. Leaving it here, maybe it helps someone.

```
- name: Connectors
      shell: curl -X GET http://myserver:8083/connectors
      register: out6
- set_fact:
        dataresult:  "{{ out6.stdout | from_json }}"
- debug: var=dataresult
```